# Perl Complex data structure in Berkeley DB

Tags: perl

folks

could someone please shed some light here

this script:

```
use strict;
use BerkeleyDB;
my $filename = "/tmp/test" ; 
unlink $filename ;
tie my %h, "BerkeleyDB::Hash", -Filename => $filename,-Flags    => DB_CREATE or die   
"Cannot open file $filename: $! $BerkeleyDB::Error\n" ;
$h{id1}{11111}{red}{2222}{3333}=1;
$h{id1}{11111}{red}{2222}{223}=1;
print "$h{id1}{11111}{red}{2222}{3333}";
untie %h ;
```

drop an alert: "Can't use string ("HASH(0x822e638)") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ./ber2.pl line 17.

Line 17 is this : $h{id1}{11111}{red}{2222}{223}=1;

what is the problem with this?

if I run script without Berkeley it works like a charm, but i need to use the DB, as i have memory issues

please help

Comment: I can't install BerkeleyDB from cpan, it gets some missing file error.  How about trying some of the other options like `tie %hash, "GDBM_File", $fn, GDBM_READER, 0644;`

Comment: @woolstar You're probably missing something like libdb-dev or an equivalent package.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this, the `BerkeleyDB` tied hash interface can only store plain scalars, not references (so no complex data structures). You can store serialized data (e.g. from `Storable`) in it, or have multiple hashes, and use some of them to store keys into other ones (you'd have to do all of the work for accessing this on your own, though). Or you could use something completely different like [DBM::Deep](http://p3rl.org/DBM::Deep), [KiokuDB](http://p3rl.org/KiokuDB) (has a BerkeleyDB backend), or [DBIx::Class](http://p3rl.org/DBIx::Class) + [SQLite](http://p3rl.org/DBD::SQLite).